# what should I do to receive enum data in spring boot http request

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Now I have a simple enum called `AppName`:

```
package misc.enumn.app;

import lombok.Getter;
import misc.enumn.BaseEnum;

/**
 * @author dolphin
 */
@Getter
public enum AppName implements BaseEnum {
    CRUISE( 1, "cruise"),
    BACK(2, "back"),
    ;
    private Integer key;
    private String value;

    AppName(Integer key, String value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void setKey(Integer key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static AppName getAppMarkByValue(String value) {
        AppName datetimeType = null;
        for (AppName type : AppName.values()) {
            if (type.name().equals(value)) {
                datetimeType = type;
            }
        }
        return datetimeType;
    }

    public static AppName getAppMarkByKey(Short key) {
        AppName datetimeType = null;
        for (AppName type : AppName.values()) {
            if (type.key.equals(key)) {
                datetimeType = type;
            }
        }
        return datetimeType;
    }
}
```

then I define a request object like this:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class UserLoginRequest implements Serializable {

    @ApiModelProperty(value = "app")
    private AppName app;

}
```

when I passed appId 1 to the server side, the server parsed AppName as `BACK`, I do not understand why it parsed as the `BACK` not 'CRUISE'? I have already define the enum parser:

```
public class IntegerCodeToEnumConverterFactory implements ConverterFactory<Integer, BaseEnum> {

    private static final Map<Class, Converter> CONVERTERS = Maps.newHashMap();

    @Override
    public <T extends BaseEnum> Converter<Integer, T> getConverter(Class<T> targetType) {
        Converter<Integer, T> converter = CONVERTERS.get(targetType);
        if (converter == null) {
            converter = new IntegerToEnumConverter<>(targetType);
            CONVERTERS.put(targetType, converter);
        }
        return converter;
    }

}
```

and add to interceptor config:

```
    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        registry.addConverterFactory(new IntegerCodeToEnumConverterFactory());
    }
```

but seem still could not parse the enum, what should I do to make it parse the app correctly? this is the wrong parse(I want 1 parsed as `CRUISE` and 2 parsed as `BACK`):

[image]

By the way, when I replace the app from enum as Integer, it could parse it correctly(receive value 1). But I think using enum may be better for readable.

```
public class IntegerToEnumConverter <T extends BaseEnum> implements Converter<Integer, T> {
    private Map<Integer, T> enumMap = Maps.newHashMap();

    public IntegerToEnumConverter(Class<T> enumType) {
        T[] enums = enumType.getEnumConstants();
        for (T e : enums) {
            enumMap.put(e.getKey(), e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public T convert(Integer source) {
        T t = enumMap.get(source);
        if (ObjectUtils.isNull(t)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("");
        }
        return t;
    }
}
```

Comment: ENUM types are just readable for us. Behind the custom names they are just Ints. This is called `ordinal`. You are not converting it correct so value 1=2nd ENUM value, because ENUM index starts from 0 as always. You need to create a custom converter for it that intercepts and converts it in a custom way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what I am doing only support http get method, if you want to parse enum in http post method. define the code like this:

```
 @JsonCreator(mode = JsonCreator.Mode.DELEGATING)
    public static AppName resolve(Integer key) {
        return mappings.get(key);
    }
```

this is my full code:

```
@Getter
public enum AppName implements BaseEnum {
    CRUISE(1, "cruise"),
    BACK(2, "back"),
    ;

    @JsonValue
    private Integer key;
    private String value;

    AppName(Integer key, String value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    private static final Map<Integer, AppName> mappings;

    static {
        Map<Integer, AppName> temp = new HashMap<>();
        for (AppName courseType : values()) {
            temp.put(courseType.key, courseType);
        }
        mappings = Collections.unmodifiableMap(temp);
    }

    @EnumConvertMethod
    @JsonCreator(mode = JsonCreator.Mode.DELEGATING)
    public static AppName resolve(Integer key) {
        return mappings.get(key);
    }

    public void setKey(Integer key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static AppName getAppMarkByValue(String value) {
        AppName datetimeType = null;
        for (AppName type : AppName.values()) {
            if (type.name().equals(value)) {
                datetimeType = type;
            }
        }
        return datetimeType;
    }

    public static AppName getAppMarkByKey(Short key) {
        AppName datetimeType = null;
        for (AppName type : AppName.values()) {
            if (type.key.equals(key)) {
                datetimeType = type;
            }
        }
        return datetimeType;
    }
}
```